# How to automate extracting attachments from email

Tags: python, automation, scripting, extract

I'm just wondering if anybody knows how I should approach the problem of automating extracting attachments from emails, putting the attachment through an excel macro, and then sending an email out! I have experience working with Python and R for data science but don't have much straight coding experience. Anybody got any resources I could read up on/scripts that exist on GitHub for something similar?

Comment: You should take a look at `imaplib` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) to download emals

Answer (score 0):

well you can use beautiful soup to automatically scrape csv/xlsx files from your email and use pandas to extract needed data and then use smptlib to send emails out.